# elasticsearch no MeCab in java.library.pat error

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch, mecab

i can't use mecab tokenizer in elasticsearch
after install elasticsearch 5.2 and mecab-ko, mecab-ko-dict, analysis-mecab-ko(elasticsearch mecab plugin), i can create index mecab tokenizer like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ES='http://localhost:9200'
ESIDX='seunjeon-idx'

echo "put setting"
curl -XPUT "${ES}/${ESIDX}/?pretty" -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "index":{
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "korean":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"seunjeon_default_tokenizer"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "seunjeon_default_tokenizer": {
            "type": "mecab_ko_standard_tokenizer",
            "mecab_args": "/usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ko-dic"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

but below curl command is not working.

```
curl -XGET "http://192.168.0.10:9200/seunjeon-idx/_analyze?
analyzer=korean&pretty" -d '삼성전자'
```

after above command is executed, below log is showed in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no MeCab in java.library.path
at org.bitbucket.eunjeon.mecab_ko_mecab_loader.MeCabLoader.lambda$static$0(MeCabLoader.java:36) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at org.bitbucket.eunjeon.mecab_ko_mecab_loader.MeCabLoader.<clinit>(MeCabLoader.java:28) ~[?:?]
at org.bitbucket.eunjeon.elasticsearch.index.analysis.MeCabKoTokenizerFactoryBase.create(MeCabKoTokenizerFactoryBase.java:74) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.CustomAnalyzer.createComponents(CustomAnalyzer.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.createComponents(AnalyzerWrapper.java:134) ~[lucene-core-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0 bbe4b08cc1fb673d0c3eb4b8455f23ddc1364124 - jim - 2017-01-17 15:57:29]
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:198) ~[lucene-core-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0 bbe4b08cc1fb673d0c3eb4b8455f23ddc1364124 - jim - 2017-01-17 15:57:29]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.simpleAnalyze(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:215) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.analyze(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:200) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:294) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:287) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:610) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:596) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

attempt & check:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libmecab
libmecab.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmecab.so.2
libmecab.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmecab.so
(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eunjeon/Yvr80vjvO74)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting 
    -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/path/to/mecab.so/dir 
in the elastic startup script.